# random seeding issue and probably constructor issue

Tags: c#, random, constructor

I want to generate a userID starting with 1000, incrementing by one for each user (1000, 1001, 1002, etc.). Neither location to seed the random statement seems to seed it... (either in the constructor or main). Why does my random statement not initialize with the 1000 seed properly in the following code?

```
public class Student
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    //constructor to initialize FullName and StudentID
    public Student(string name, int ID)
    {
        FullName = name;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        StudentID = rnd.Next(1000, 1050); // creates a number greater than 1000
        return;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ID: {0}\n Name: {1}", StudentID, FullName);
    }
}

public class StudentTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student student1 = new Student("Amy Lee", 1000);
        Student student2 = new Student("John Williams", 1001);
        Console.WriteLine(student1);
        Console.WriteLine(student2);
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit program");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: All you are doing is setting the `StudentID` property to a random value between 1000 and 1050 using an instance of Random which is seeded by the current time (the behavior of the default constructor). The constructor takes an `ID` parameter, but you aren't doing anything with it. It's not clear to me what your expectations are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to generate a userID starting with 1000, incrementing by one for each user (1000, 1001, 1002, etc.).

Then you should not try to do that using a random generator, because it will return **random** instead of sequential numbers.

Given your sample code, where you are (1) not using threads, (2) not using a database (3) and not saving the created `Student` instances, the simplest way to achieve what you want is the following:

```
public class Student
{
    private static int _curID = 1000;

    public static int GenerateNextID()
    {
        var id = _curID;
        _curID++;
        return id;
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; private set; }

    //constructor to initialize FullName and StudentID
    public Student(string name, int ID)
    {
        FullName = name;
        StudentID = ID;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ID: {0}\n Name: {1}", StudentID, FullName);
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
public class StudentTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student student1 = new Student("Amy Lee", Student.GenerateNextID());
        Student student2 = new Student("John Williams", Student.GenerateNextID());
        Console.WriteLine(student1);
        Console.WriteLine(student2);
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit program");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Random` generates random numbers, not sequential ones.

Declare an `int` variable and increment it for each `StudentID`.

```
public class Student
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    private static int _currentId = 1000;

    public Student(string name)
    {
        FullName = name;
        StudentID = _currentId++;
        return;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ID: {0}\n Name: {1}", StudentID, FullName);
    }
}
```